# "system:ExtrinsicFailed" error when submitting transactions

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, extrinsic, transactions, substrate-front-end

I'm trying to call the `setName` method of nicks pallet:
[image]

However, when I run click "Signed" I get the error on the right, which is:

```
system:ExtrinsicFailed
[{"Module":{"index":"10","error":"0x01000000"}},{"weight":"50,000,000","class":"Normal","paysFee":"Yes"}]
```

Of note is that this error isn't specific to setName or nicks pallet, as if I try it with other pallets too then I get the same error.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What node are you running? Where did you get the runtime config from?  
Maybe the name is too long or too short.

Comment: You have to look up the index and error in your runtime to see what it is. To understand how to interpret errors, take a look here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-errors

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort it out thanks to Bruno. When I checked the "PolkadotJS Apps Explorer" I found that the name I was setting was too short (the minimum character length is 8 characters or something). When I made the nickname longer then it worked fine.